# Can I edit mysqli_result object in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I got mysqli_result object from successfully query

I wanna modify this mysqli_result object using if statement..

```
 $party_set = find_all_parties(); //mysqli_result object

 while($party = mysqli_fetch_assoc($party_set)){
     $locArr =split(",",$party["loc"]);    
     $lat = $locArr[0];
     $lng = $locArr[1]; 

     if(distance($currentLat,$currentLng,$lat,$lng) > $seletedDistance ){             
         //I want remove the row if this condition is true             
     }
 }
```

How can I modify `$party_set`??

Comment: what do you mean `modify the object`? what are you going to modify there anyway? what are you trying to do? whats the expected outcome?

Comment: As I commented in my code,,I wanna delete the row that meet my condition statement..@Ghost

Comment: no you cannot delete that row, its not inside the `mysqli result object`. its not inside `$party_set`, you can only skip the iteration, or make the necessary `WHERE` clause to exclude it.

Comment: I have poor English conversation skill, so it's hard to explain what I want to..T.T..My final purpose is making a modified $party_set.. which don't have the row meeting if condition.. do you understand my core issue? I'm sorry again my poor English..@Ghost

Comment: yes i understand what you're trying to do, but it is not possible. the values are not inside `$party_set`, because its a mysqli result object. thats why you have to fetch those results first, the result set resource is there but not the rows. just like my comment above, either make a select `WHERE`, where it filters distance > selected distance or skip by using `continue` in the while loop

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify a mysqli result object. That object is just a handle that lets you access the MySQL result set on the MySQL server. You cannot change that either. Your options are:

1. Get the data from the result object into an array, e.g. `$data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`. It is then a normal array you can modify as you wish. If you're doing this in a loop, simply *don't* put the row into your data array if you don't like it.
2. Make a query with a `WHERE` clause that excludes the unwanted rows from the beginning.
3. If you mean that you want to delete specific rows from the database entirely, you need to do a separate `DELETE FROM ..` query, just removing it from the result set would do nothing. Again, you can do this very easily in one go with a proper `WHERE` clause, e.g. `DELETE FROM .. WHERE (lat, lon, something something..)`.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to modify the original object but to create a new array :

```
 $party_set = find_all_parties(); //mysqli_result object
 $new_party_set = array();
 while($party = mysqli_fetch_assoc($party_set)){
     $locArr =split(",",$party["loc"]);    
     $lat = $locArr[0];
     $lng = $locArr[1]; 

     if(distance($currentLat,$currentLng,$lat,$lng) <= $seletedDistance ){             
         $new_party_set[] = $party;
     }
 }
```

if you need to modify the database as well and not only the php set, then run another query using IN operator .

Answer (score 1):

Thank you every one.. I solve this problem by very silly way..

I made a new query string like this..

> ```
> function checkDistance($currentLat,$currentLng,$setDistance){
>     global $connection;
>     $party_set = find_all_parties(); //mysqli_result object
>     $query = "SELECT * ";
>     $query .= "FROM party ";
>     $query .= "WHERE ";
>
>     while($party = mysqli_fetch_assoc($party_set)){
>          $locArr =split(",",$party["loc"]);    
>          $lat = $locArr[0];
>          $lng = $locArr[1];
>          $id= $party["id"];
>      
>          //세팅 된 거리보다 거리가 작으면
>          if(distance($currentLat,$currentLng,$lat,$lng) <= $setDistance ){
>
>               $query .= "id = {$id} OR ";
>           }
>
>       }
>
>      //delete last "OR "    $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query) - 3);
>      echo $query;
>
>      $dt_party_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
>      confirm_query($dt_party_set);
>
>      return $dt_party_set;
>  }
> ```

anyway,, thank you very much

and after my project done I'll retry using the way what you recommended ...good luck everyone