# Changing Mysqli_result before returning result to rest of application

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, resultset

I have around 75 php existing scripts that access mysql database similar to this pseudo code:

```
$query="SELECT * from table";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //use the rows
    }
}
```

I was recently forced to encrypt all the database fields individually, so now when those 75 php scripts run as shown above, all the $row come back with all the fields encrypted, thus unusable.

So rather than change all the 75 php scripts to decode each field, i wanted to create a function that executes the mysqli_query, and then decrypts all the fields, and returns the result as if it was returned by the mysqli_query, but decrypted. Something like

```
function QueryAndDecrypt($conn,$query){
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $row=decrypt($row);
        } 
    }
    return $result;  <<----- return result with fields decrypted
}

// now all 75 scripts would have to change just one line to call above

$query="SELECT * from table";
$result=QueryAndDecrypt($conn,$query);  <<--- change only 1 line
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //use the rows as normal decrypted
    }
}
```

As you can see I just want to change that one line in all the 75 scripts so that it will do the same thing as before, and the result will come back with all the fields already decrypted.

I tried writing this QueryAndDecrypt function, but when i change the result from mysqli_result $row as shown above it wont change because the result from mysql is some sort of set that is not changeable (I was told), or something like that.

So is there anyway to do this by writing a common function that can be called from all the scripts which does the sql query and also decrypts the result in such a way that it can be accessed by all the other scripts like a regular mysql query result?

Can anybody help, im "fresh off the boat", so i dont know sql that well or php, i'm so desperate right now because all the scripts are broken because of this!!

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Result set not updating after mySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381066/result-set-not-updating-after-mysql-query)

Comment: If you were using the msqli in OO style, you could just create a class that fakes the method to return the number of rows (1 if you got any), and returns an array of the columns for a row. But you have the procedureal style, so you would have to edit the num rows line and the fetch line.

Comment: There is no solution on the other question

Comment: Ans, it's not a duplicate. He wants to simulate the query.

Comment: Is the encryption on the fields of a type that mysql can decrypt? If so, you could modify the queries in the function before executing them.

Comment: Sloan, maybe, i can change the encryption to anything i want, even something the database can do, but i was told that I should not send unencrypted data to mysql over the connection, if i let the database do the encryption, then i would have to send clear text over the connection to the database before it can encrypt it

Comment: I would think this would be a common thing because if credit card numbers and social security numbers are stored in a database, dont they store it as encrypted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I edit mysqli\_result object in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27456792/can-i-edit-mysqli-result-object-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't modify the rows of the result and then somehow 'unfetch' them back into the result to be fetched again.

But you can fix your code by changing one line:

```
$query = "SELECT * from table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = MyFetchAssocAndDecrypt($result)) {   <<--- change only 1 line
        //use the rows as normal decrypted
    }
}
```

You'd have to write functions something like this:

```
function MyDecrypt(&$item, $key) {
    $item = openssl_decrypt($item, OPENSSL_CIPHER_AES_256_CBC, MY_SECRET_KEY);
}

function MyFetchAssocAndDecrypt($conn, $result){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conn, $result);
    array_walk($row, 'MyDecrypt');
    return $row;  <<----- return row with fields decrypted
}
```

PS: You mentioned the requirement that you aren't supposed to send unencrypted data over the network to the database. That wouldn't be my concern, because you can use a VPN or else connect to the database via SSL.

The greater concern is that the *query* that contains your plaintext data and the plaintext encryption password would be written to database logs on the MySQL server, and these logs are not encrypted.

There are some optional extensions to MySQL that promise to do full-database encryption, but these extensions overlook the query logs.